# How to improve my scroll function, to tame the sensitivity and reverse the action. Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello I have created a website which works around scrolling to trigger loading the next "page". Each page is a div with a class which is shown and hidden by scrolling down. I would like to reverse this by having an upscroll to load the previous section. Using a usb mouse this transition works quite smoothly by turning the mouse wheel slightly the transition happens. However on my laptop the tracker pad has a really sensitive scroll which changes multiple divs at a time.

The link to the site is: www.alexanderJrichardson.com.

Thank you in advance.

Here is some relvant code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
    });
        var currentView = 'Page1';
        var display = $('.' + currentView).css('display');
        if (display == 'block') {
           change('currentView')();
        }
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 5){
              switch(currentView){
                 case "Page1":
                 changePage1();
                 break;
                 case "Page2":
                 changePage2();
                 break;
                 case "Page3":
                 changePage3();
                 break;
                 case "Page4":
                 changePage4();
                 break;
                 case "Page5":
                 changePage5();
              }
            }
        });

        function changePage5(){
                   setTimeout(function() {          
                   $('.menuDiv').css("display", "none");
                   }, 100);
                   $('.fadeInRight').toggleClass("fadeOutRight").toggleClass("fadeInRight");
                   $('.fadeInLeft').toggleClass("fadeOutLeft").toggleClass("fadeInLeft");
                   $('.fadeInUp').toggleClass("fadeOutUp").toggleClass("fadeInUp");
                   $('.fadeInDown').toggleClass("fadeOutDown").toggleClass("fadeInDown");
                   $('.fadeOutRight').toggleClass("fadeInRight").toggleClass("fadeOutRight");
                   $('.fadeOutLeft').toggleClass("fadeInLeft").toggleClass("fadeOutLeft");
                   $('.fadeOutUp').toggleClass("fadeInUp").toggleClass("fadeOutUp");
                   $('.fadeOutDown').toggleClass("fadeInDown").toggleClass("fadeOutDown");
                   setTimeout(function() {
                   $('.Page1').css("display", "block");
                   }, 100);
                   $('.Page2').css("display", "none");
                   $('.Page3').css("display", "none");
                   $('.Page4').css("display", "none");
                   $('.Page5').css("display", "none");  
                   currentView = "Page1";
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some boolean value to determine, if scrolling is allowed:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if (!scrollAllowed) {
    return;
  }
  //your scrolling code here
  scrollAllowed = false;
  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollAllowed = true;
  }, timeout);
});
```

This will prevent scrolling first 0.1 sec if `timeout` is 100.
Don't use a "magic" number, use a `timeout` variable instead. This will allow aesy changes in future. Also, avoid functions like `changePage5()`, us `changePage(index)`. This is much more flexible.

**Edit:** full code to achieve the desired result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});

//number of pages you have
var viewCount = 5;
var scrollAllowed = true;
var timeout = 100;
var currentView = 'Page1';
var display = $('.' + currentView).css('display');
if (display == 'block') {
   change('currentView')();
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (!scrollAllowed) {
    return;
  }
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 5) {
    changePage(currentView.substring(4));
  }
  scrollAllowed = false;
  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollAllowed = true;
  }, timeout);
});

function changePage(index){
   setTimeout(function() {
      $('.menuDiv').css("display", "none");
     }, timeout);
   $('.fadeInRight').toggleClass("fadeOutRight").toggleClass("fadeInRight");
   $('.fadeInLeft').toggleClass("fadeOutLeft").toggleClass("fadeInLeft");
   $('.fadeInUp').toggleClass("fadeOutUp").toggleClass("fadeInUp");
   $('.fadeInDown').toggleClass("fadeOutDown").toggleClass("fadeInDown");
   $('.fadeOutRight').toggleClass("fadeInRight").toggleClass("fadeOutRight");
   $('.fadeOutLeft').toggleClass("fadeInLeft").toggleClass("fadeOutLeft");
   $('.fadeOutUp').toggleClass("fadeInUp").toggleClass("fadeOutUp");
   $('.fadeOutDown').toggleClass("fadeInDown").toggleClass("fadeOutDown");

   //this hides all pages
   for (var i = 1; i <= viewCount; i++) {
     $(".Page" + i).css("display", "none");
   }

   //choose next page number
   index++;
   if (index > viewCount) {
     //loop from last to first
     index = 1;
   }
   setTimeout(function() {                
     $('.Page' + index).css("display", "block");
   }, timeout);
   currentView = "Page" + index;
};
```

**Note:** I'm not sure, that it will work with all modifications. I don't know how you functions `changePageN` look like, so I was acting assuming they do all the same. If this doesn't work maybe you will need to go back to using `changePage1, changePage2 ...`

Comment: I think I see what you mean, would it be cheeky of me to ask you to rewrite the current code with this answer integrated. Thanks